# Displaying an ArrayList in FragmentList

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, adapter

I have the following problem: I need to show Data which i get from a Database in a ListFragment. The programm is finally running but the ListFragment is still empty.
(Data is recieved which can be seen via logD.)
It's my first question here so i hope im not missing anything. I would appreciate help a lot. Also sorry for  bat formating of the code kinda strugeling with this.

My Files:

1.) Main Activity (changing the Fragment)

```
public void onFragmentInteraction(List<Strecke> uri) {    
    Log.d("StreckeMain", uri.toString());

    Fragment Itemfragment  = new ItemFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transactionsearch = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transactionsearch.replace(R.id.content, Itemfragment);
    transactionsearch.addToBackStack(null);
    transactionsearch.commit();
}
```

2.) Fragment

```
public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {    
    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private StreckeAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Strecke> streckeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public ItemFragment() {
    }

    // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static ItemFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new StreckeAdapter(streckeList);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mLinearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;

        // Set the adapter
        /*if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            mAdapter = new StreckeAdapter(streckeList);
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }
            //recyclerView.setAdapter((RecyclerView.Adapter) mListener);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return view;*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
          //  throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                  //  + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyItem item);
    }
}
```

3.) Adapter

```
 public class StreckeAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<StreckeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
            public List<Strecke> streckeList;

            public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                public TextView zeitAbfahrt, Ziel, zeitZiel, tel, mail;

                public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                    super(view);
                    zeitAbfahrt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.i_zeit);
                    Ziel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.i_ziel);
                    zeitZiel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.i_zielZeit);
                    tel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.i_tel);
                    mail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.i_mail);
                }
            }    

            public StreckeAdapter(List<Strecke> streckeList) {
                this.streckeList = streckeList;
                Log.d("SAdapter", "StreckeAdapter enterd ");
            }


            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false);

                return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
                Strecke strecke = streckeList.get(position);
                holder.zeitAbfahrt.setText(strecke.getZeitAbfahrt());
                holder.Ziel.setText(strecke.getZiel());
                holder.zeitZiel.setText(strecke.getZeitZiel());
                holder.tel.setText(strecke.gettel());
                holder.mail.setText(strecke.getmail());

            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return streckeList.size();
            }
        }
```

4.) Layout for an Item

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/i_zeit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:text="Zeit Hier"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/i_ziel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:text="Ziel"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/i_zielZeit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:text="Zeit Ziel"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/i_tel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:text="Telefonnummer"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/i_mail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:text="e-mail"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

5.) Layout ItemList

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In `onFragmentInteraction()`: do you do anything else with `List<Strecke> uri` besides logging? (maybe you forgot to post all the relevant parts?)

Comment: well im switching to the fragment which should display the ListArray in a ListFragment. The data comes through the StreckeAdapter i guess. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: But the List (new ArrayList<>() ) is empty. How do you add data to this List? The adapter can only show what you hand over to it. (TL;DR: pass uri to the instance() method so you can access the data in the Fragment)

Comment: which instance() method do you mean? the data is already in the list because logd outputs the values. I'm sorry this is kinda my first time programming for android.

Comment: You log the values in the MainActivity: "Log.d("StreckeMain", uri.toString());" But you create a new Fragment instance with a new empty List which you then pass to the adapter in the Fragment's onCreateView(). As far as I can see you never try to pass a List from the MainActivity to the Fragment. To better understand what I'm trying to tell you please log streckeList.size() in the Fragment code. From what you posted here it should always be zero, no matter where you place the Log.d(...) statement.

Comment: Thank you. Got it to work with a getter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem really was that the Array (uri) wasn't passed to the Fragment. I solved this simple, but not great.
Just added a getter in my ActivityMain and then accessed it in the Fragment.